# Visual Basic.Net 2010 Exception Error meaning

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ms-access-2007

Can anyone Help me to figure out whats the meaning of this error statement.I keep getting this error statement:-

index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

Below is my coding

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class form2


    Dim Mycn As OleDbConnection
    Dim Command As OleDbCommand
    Dim icount As Integer
    Dim SQLstr As String

    Private Sub Button1_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Try
            Mycn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\lenovo\Documents\Final year stuff\BookStoreDb.mdb;")
            Mycn.Open()

            SQLstr = String.Format("INSERT INTO login VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
            Command = New OleDbCommand(SQLstr, Mycn)


            icount = Command.ExecuteNonQuery
            MessageBox.Show(icount)


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " - " & ex.Source)
            Mycn.Close()
        End Try
    End Sub



    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Close()

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: You aren't filling in all of the arguments in your call to String.Format.

Comment: you have 5 placeholders for String.Format, but only 2 values.  That SQL is open to SQL injection attacks, you should use Parameters and both problems will go away.  Also, the ticks ( ` ' `) in the SQL string, force all the values to string, which may or may not be what you want depending on the table.

Comment: isit i need to put all the fields in the login table or the fields that i want to insert data?

Comment: if you are only supplying SOME table values, you need to change the SQL to tell it WHICH columns you wish to INSERT, then you can provide just those values: `"INSERT INTO Login ([User], [Password]) VALUES ('{0}','{1}')"`.  But the big problem is [SQL injection](http://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/1070452).  Parameters will eliminate that and issues with ticks in SQL

Answer (score 0):

As Plutonix suggested, just specify the two fields.

You can combine that with the parameters so you are also safe from injection attacks.

Try the following:

```
SQLstr = String.Format("INSERT INTO Login (User, Password) VALUES ('{0}','{1}')", TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text)
Command = New OleDbCommand(SQLstr, Mycn)
```